# two encrypting / hashing case, which one is best

Tags: cryptography, aes, pbkdf2

Thinking about these below two cases, which one is best and most secure one

1st case

```
//key1 generated from static salt and user password, because in case attacker don't know about source code (bad assumption, but still my assumption), attacker have only hashed or encrypted data + random generated salt
staticSalt = "StaticSalt"
key1 = pbkdf2(userPassword, staticSalt, iteration)

//key2 generated from key1 and randomSalt, this will be actual key to be used for encryption
randomSalt = GenerateRandomSalt()
key2 = pbkdf2(key1, randomSalt, iteration)

aes.Key = Key2
aes.IV = aes.GenerateIV()
```

or

2nd case

```
//directly generate key from randomSalt and password
randomSalt = GenerateRandomSalt()
key1 = pbkdf2(userPassword, randomSalt, iteration)

aes.Key = Key1
aes.IV = aes.GenerateIV()
```

My question is, is there any drawback in using 1st case, will it increasing or decreasing entropy, or making is less secure?

or 2nd case is far more better and secure way to do

Looking for answer from some crypto expert.

Comment: The first case is called "peppering the password", and you're doing it in a strange way. You're using a random salt in both cases, which is good, but what you're doing in the first case is negatively creative, adds complexity, and almost completely pointless. Go with the second case, it's the standard.

Comment: In first case, in first step using "static salt" then in second step using "random salt", while in 2nd case, only 1 step that is using the "random salt"., while from peppering the password what I know to add something to password before passing to hashing algo. While here I think that I am not peppering the password.

Comment: A pepper is basically a static secondary or primary salt. So, **yes, you _are_ peppering the password**. Other than increasing the iterations, the first part of your first case is useless.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make a difference other than the number of iterations of the hash. Entropy doesn't matter in a salt, only the uniqueness matters. Random input is the easiest way to get uniqueness but any uniqueness is equally valuable.

The first step really doesn't add anything as a rainbow table can be built for the first step and give inputs to try for the second in bulk.

Comment: So it means that first case is not adding benefit, but more important is that it is also not bringing any security issues or compromising security when comparing with 2nd case?

Comment: Right, unless I missed something the second example is just the second half of the first. The second part of it is fine as long as the iterations are high enough but the first call is just a waste of time.